# ctrl + ] not working even after installing ctags in Vim

Tags: javascript, vim, ctags

I have just installed ctags and am trying to use it in Vim in web-development.

First I have set `set tags=tags;/`. This will help the tag to find the source from the project directory to root.

I have run `ctags -R` in the project directory and a tags file has been generated. While generating the tags file it throws a warning :

```
ctags: Warning: ignoring null tag in filename.js
```

However, when I use the shortcuts(like ctrl+]) they do not open the source(jump to definition) files. Instead an error shows `tag not found filename.js`

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Did you 'cs add' your tags file?

Comment: I guess I haven't. How to 'cs add' the tags file?

Comment: from within gvim run `:exe cs add cscope.out`

Comment: @IgalS. the OP uses ctags, not cscope.

Comment: Could you take a look at the content of the tags file?

Comment: Consider not to deal with ctags manually, but use my plugin Indexer ( http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3221 ) instead, it will do all the work automatically.

Comment: Try `:tselect ctrl-d`, where `ctrl-d` requires pressing the ctrl and d keys and the space is _required_.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the `./` prefix, so that the search starts with the current file's path, not the current working directory. And you don't need the `/` stop directory; the following should work:

```
set tags=./tags;
```

For troubleshooting, the `tagfiles()` function prints all found tags files. Check that your is found via

```
:echo tagfiles()
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Ingo Karkat said, you could also test manually by changing your current working directory to where your tags files are.

```
:pwd
```

Use pwd to check if your are not already there. If not you change directory to your tag file directory.

```
:cd /your/tag/file/directory
```

Then try again <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>.